# Unable to login via twitter using satellizer

Tags: angularjs, satellizer

I have a angular web application and want to twitter and facebook login. I used satellizer module for both. Facebook login working fine for me. But when i clicked on twitter login button a blank popup window appears and nothing to happen. Please help me. In the documentation the suggest no need to configure for twitter. even i configure using the following code

```
$authProvider.twitter({
        url: '/auth/twitter',
        responseType:'token'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you have to put the the redirection code in server side mentioned in the following link.
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/node/server.js